# SSMS context menu on temporal (system-versioned) table doesn't show table actions

Tags: ssms

After enabling Temporal on my table, SSMS groups it with history table and context menu on my table doesn't show table actions, like "Select Top 1000 Rows", "Edit Top 200 Rows", etc.
Is there some fix or workaround to this behavior?

Update: looks like this is the case with LocalDB, when connected to Azure Database temporal table context menu works fine.